# Blocking ip with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ip-blocking

I have a htaccess file with following code when trying to block an IP:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

ErrorDocument 404 /errors.php

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 188.143.232.
Allow from all
```

Blocking my own IP works when browsing www.example.com, but it does not block for anything else (like www.example.com/index.php or www.example.com/home, ....). The htaccess is located in the same directory as index.php (httpdocs folder).

How can I get it to work?

Comment: The order is allow, deny, but your allow statement is at the bottom.

Comment: @Psioniax this doesn't make a difference. Allow,deny is the order in which the statements below are used. I also tested changing the order (allow from all first, then deny from...), which doesn't change anything in the behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a mod-rewrite based ip-blocking to block unwanted ip(s) :

```
RewriteEngine on

#--if client ip==188.143.232
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^188\.143\.232
#--forbid the request
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: This does work properly. Any idea what gives the strange behavior for my method? What are the differences between these methods? And if I want to add some other IP's, I always add the two lines, or is RewriteCond alone ok?

Comment: @Pepe  I think the order of allow and deny directive was not correct.  If you want to block multiple ips ,you could use multiple RewriteConds with OR condition. **RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.2\.3\.4 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^2\.2\.3\.4**

Comment: And the differences between the two methods? Also, the order doesn't making any difference (as said in comments on the opening post). And last: blocking the IP range now works quite well, every IP in the range manages to do 1 GET request (so every few minutes). Is this normal, or should they be completely invisible in the access log?